# How to write to a uniform buffer using mapAsync with WebGPU

Tags: javascript, webgpu, wgsl

I have a uniform buffer that is created like this:

```js
const temp = new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
const positionBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size: temp.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
    mappedAtCreation: true,
});

const positionArray = new Float32Array(positionBuffer.getMappedRange());
positionArray.set(temp);
positionBuffer.unmap();
```

When I want to update the position uniform, I try to run `positionBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.WRITE)` but it fails with the following warning telling me to add the MAP_WRITE flag:

> The buffer usages (BufferUsage::(CopySrc|Uniform)) do not contain BufferUsage::MapWrite.

But when I then add `MAP_WRITE`, I get a different warning:

> Buffer usages (BufferUsage::(MapWrite|CopyDst|Index)) is invalid. If a buffer usage contains BufferUsage::MapWrite the only other allowed usage is BufferUsage::CopySrc.

This is stating that with MAP_WRITE, the only other allowed flag is COPY_SRC, meaning I would have to remove my UNIFORM flag.

I obviously need the uniform flag and probably the copy_dst flag (or maybe not?). I would assume that it would be better to map the buffer and directly write to GPU memory rather than any other way, so how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am learning WebGPU currently and had this same question. As mentioned before, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GPUDevice/createBuffer#validation) says that a MAP_WRITE usage can only be paired with a COPY_SRC usage and nothing else. Similarly, MAP_READ can only be paired with a COPY_DST.

In Vulkan (I believe), you are free to create a buffer with all of these usages (if the implementation supports it). However, it is commonly not very performant to do so, and so instead people use staging buffers. This design pattern has you create a main buffer which is only GPU accessible -- this is the one you will use in your shader. You also create a second buffer accessible from both the CPU and GPU. This one is your staging buffer. You will write into your staging buffer from the CPU, then copy it to your main buffer on the GPU, and then use your main buffer in your shader.

WebGPU seems to require this design pattern based on the restrictions to the usage flags. So to get around your issue, create a staging buffer and a main buffer like so:

```js
stagingBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size:  BUFFER_SIZE,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.MAP_WRITE |
        GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
});

mainBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size:  BUFFER_SIZE,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM  |
        GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
});
```

You can now write data from the CPU to your staging buffer like so:

```js
await this.stagingBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.WRITE);

let data = new Float32Array(this.stagingBuffer.getMappedRange());
data.set(new Float32Array([ /* Whatever you like here */ ]));
stagingBuffer.unmap();
```

Then, during your command buffer creation, you'll want to add in the copy operation:

```js
commandEncoder.copyBufferToBuffer(
    stagingBuffer, 0,  // buffer, offset
    mainBuffer,    0,  // buffer, offset
    BUFFER_SIZE,
);

// Then you would use commandEncoder.beginRenderPass for example
```

Note that I'm also a beginner with this API, so I may have made mistakes or use suboptimal design patterns. If that's the case please let me know and I'll update my answer. Hope this helps anyone out there who didn't see a clear way forward with the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

In WebGPU, if you want to map a buffer for writing (`GPUMapMode.WRITE`), you need to ensure that the buffer's usage flags are set appropriately. In your case, you need to include `GPUBufferUsage.MAP_WRITE` in the usage flags along with `GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM` and `GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC`.

Here's an updated code snippet to reflect the changes:

```
const temp = new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
const positionBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size: temp.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC | GPUBufferUsage.MAP_WRITE,
    mappedAtCreation: true,
});

const positionArray = new Float32Array(positionBuffer.getMappedRange());
positionArray.set(temp);
positionBuffer.unmap();
With the updated code, you should be able to call positionBuffer.mapAsync(GPUMapMode.WRITE) successfully.
```

Additionally, since you're using `GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC`, it seems like you may be planning to use this buffer as a source for copying data to other buffers. If that's the case, make sure to include GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST in the usage flags when creating the destination buffers.

```
const destinationBuffer = device.createBuffer({
    size: temp.byteLength,
    usage: GPUBufferUsage.UNIFORM | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
});
```

By including GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST, you can use copyBufferToBuffer or similar methods to efficiently copy data from the position buffer to the destination buffer.

Remember to adjust your shader code accordingly to use the updated buffer usage flags and ensure the appropriate binding types are used in the shader layout.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately though, whenever I try to add the MAP_WRITE flag it throws an error saying that the only other flag allowed is COPY_SRC. More info in the question.

Comment: To resolve this warning, you need to ensure that you are using the correct combination of buffer usage flags. In your case, if you want to map the buffer for writing (BufferUsage::MapWrite), you should not include the BufferUsage::Index flag. Instead, you can use BufferUsage::CopySrc if it is applicable to your specific use case.

Comment: It's saying that I can't use any other flag except COPY_SRC, meaning I would have to remove my UNIFORM flag which will break my program. After a few days of research I think that writing to buffers using `mapAsync` isn't a thing in WebGPU yet, or there's a specific reason it can't be implemented. Thank you for the answer though; my COPY_SRC flag should have indeed been COPY_DST.

Comment: So investigating this more. Faster ways to use mapAsync with uniform buffers. One is to bunch up your uniforms. Instead of one uniform buffer per object, try one uniform buffer holding uniforms for multiple objects at different offsets. The reason is it's always faster to do less work so one call to writeBuffer for N objects is faster then N calls for N objects even if the amount of data is the same.

Comment: Another is to keep your transferbuffers mapped, possibly double buffering them. So, at render time, grab an already mapped transferbuffer, copy the data to it, unmap it, issue a copyBufferToBuffer, submit your command buffer, then mapAsync the transferbuffer (and on promise put it back in your cache of transferbuffers).